# Pypot - не создается объект в сцене V-REP

Tags: python

## Проблема

Имеется код:

```py
from pypot.vrep import *

close_all_connections()
print('Closed')

floor = VrepIO(scene='simple_scene.ttt')
print('Opened')

floor.start_simulation()
print('Started')

print('position - ', floor.get_object_position('Sphere'))
floor.set_object_position('Sphere', [0, 0.5, 0.3])

floor.add_cube('myCube', [0,0,0.3], [0.1,0.1,0.1], 10)
floor.change_object_name("myCube", "myCube1")
print('Name changed')

floor.stop_simulation()
print('Stopped')
```

### Что ожидается

В сцене `simple_scene` уже имеется несколько объектов, включая `Sphere`.

Код должен по порядку:

- Вывести позицию сферы
- Переместить сферу
- Создать куб
- Переименовать куб

### Что в итоге

На строке `floor.change_object_name` происходит ошибка - `RemoteError`: **невозможно найти куб 'myCube'**.

Просмотрев вывод программы и запустившуюся симуляцию в V-REP, видно что позиция сферы вывелась корректно, затем в сцене сфера переместилась. А функция `floor.add_cube` ничего не сделала. Никаких ошибок по этому поводу нигде нигде не отобразилось.

## Локализация

Поразобравшись в коде модуля `pypot.vrep.io`, мы увидели что **большинство** команд (как `set_object_position` в коде выше) выполняется с помощью метода `call_remote_api(func_name: str, arg1, arg2, ...)`. Но **некоторые** (`add_cube` -> `_create_pure_shape`) команды выполняются не напрямую через `call_remote_api`, а через внутреннюю функцию `_inject_lua_code`.

[image: Функция inject_lua_code и ее использование]

Мы выяснили, почему это так. Дело в том, что внутри `call_remote_api` есть объект `api_binding`, у которого есть методы с названиями, которые передаются первым аргументом в `call_remote_api`. Но **некоторых** функций там нет. Мы попытались напрямую вызвать call_remote_api('simCreatePureShape', args) - выкинулась ошибка **об отсутствующем методе**. Стало ясно, что для подобных функций тут предусмотрен обход через `_inject_lua_code`, который должен отправлять команду на выполнение кода lua в **консоли** V-REP. Для создания куба это будет `simCreatePureShape(0, ...)`. Мы попробовали выполнить эту функцию прямо в **консоли V-REP** - выполнено **успешно**, куб создан.

Исходя из этих фактов, стало ясно что проблема именно в нерабочем `_inject_lua_code`. Мы проверили другие команды, которые также выполняются через этот метод - **все не работают**, втихую ничего не делают.

### Что мы пробовали

Мы переопределили метод `_inject_lua_code` и предположили, что кодировка строки с lua кодом (`lua_code`) срабатывает не так, как надо именно в нашей ОС. На скрин мы видим, что там сначала берется массив байтов `lua_code.encode()`, затем преобразовывается в немного другой формат байтов (не совсем понял, как именно, и зачем). Мы попробовали следующие манипуляции:

- Отправка строки `lua_code` "как есть", в виде строки.
- Отправка в виде массива байтов `lua_code.encode()` без последующих преобразований
- `.encode('UTF-8')`, `'UTF-16'`, `'ASCII'`

### Какую помощь ожидаем

Если у вас после прочтения появились какие-нибудь мысли, что мы еще можем попробовать, пожалуйста поделитесь ими.

Для теста у себя - установите CoppeliaSim, [pypot](https://github.com/poppy-project/pypot)

Также, мы пробовали поискать логи V-REP, в надежде увидеть там ошибки API - логи не нашли. Если вы знаете, где могут находиться логи - скажите.

#### Спецификации

- ОС: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- V-REP: CoppeliaSim Edu 4.3.0, Edu 4.2.0 (пробовали обе версии)